# Compressed image transport plugin uses which jpeg encoding library?

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello Some time ago, I remember /compressedimage topic was consuming 700KB/s bandwidth for 640*480 image @ 30 fps at 80% quality.

After that, I think I started learning gstreamer and I re-install libjpeg-dev or libjpeg-turbo8 or something I did.

Now when I resume working on /compressedimage topic, I am realizing that it is consuming 1.2MB/s bandwidth for same 640*480 @ 30fps at 80% quality.

**Which jpeg library does compressed image transport plugin use?**

I am wishing to have lowest bandwidth possible for 80% jpeg quality.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/338644/compressed-image-transport-plugin-uses-which-jpeg-encoding-library?/) by [JeyP4](https://answers.ros.org/users/38257/jeyp4/) on ROS Answers with karma: 62 on 2019-11-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

https://github.com/ros-perception/image_transport_plugins/blob/indigo-devel/compressed_image_transport/src/compressed_publisher.cpp#L137

OpenCV's.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2020-04-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0